Why does authInstance.isSignedIn.get() return always null?
i am trying to build a web game and at first I have this JavaScript "App.js", where the user can log in via google and if he is logged in, he can log out.
But authInstance.isSignedIn.get() does always return null, after the user is logged in
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import LoginButton from "./components/login";
import LogoutButton from "./components/logout";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import Dashboard from './components/dashboard'; // Dashboard-Seite
import Search from './components/search'; // Dashboard-Seite
import { gapi } from 'gapi-script';
const clientId = "MyApiURL";


function App() {
  const [isLoggedIn, setIsLoggedIn] = useState(false); // State für den Anmeldestatus


  useEffect(() => {
      function start() {
          gapi.client.init({
              clientId: clientId,
              scope: ""

          }).then(() => {
        const authInstance = gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance();

        // Setzt den Status basierend auf der aktuellen Anmeldung
        setIsLoggedIn(authInstance.isSignedIn.get());

        // Hört auf Änderungen des Anmeldestatus
        authInstance.isSignedIn.listen(setIsLoggedIn);
      });

      };

      gapi.load('client:auth2', start);

  }, []);

  
  
  return (
   <Router>
      <div className="App">
        <Routes>
          {/* Login-Route */}
          <Route path="/" element={isLoggedIn ? <LogoutButton /> : <LoginButton />} />
           <Route path="/search" element={<Search />} /> {/* Route für Search */}
          
          {/* Dashboard-Route nach erfolgreichem Login */}
          <Route path="/dashboard" element={<Dashboard isLoggedIn={isLoggedIn} />} />
        </Routes>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;

This is the Login code. When the LoginButton is hit, this is carried out.
import {GoogleLogin} from 'react-google-login';
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import { gapi } from 'gapi-script';

const clientId = "...";



function Login(){
     const navigate = useNavigate();  // Initialisiere useNavigate

    const onSuccess = (res) => {
        console.log("LOGIN SUCCESS! Current user: ", res.profileObj);
        navigate('/dashboard'); 
    }

    const onFailure = (res) => {
        console.log("LOGIN FAILED! res: ", res);
    }
    
    return(
        <div id = "signInButton">
            <GoogleLogin
                clientId={clientId}
                buttonText="Login"
                onSuccess={onSuccess}
                onFailure={onFailure}
                cookiePolicy={'single_host_origin'}
                isSignedIn={true}
            />
        

        </div>
    )
}
export default Login;


Did you try looking at the examples this library provides in github?  It doesn't look like you're using what they use here: https://github.com/LucasAndrad/gapi-script-live-example/blob/master/src/components/GoogleLogin.js

Yes, I replaced all the code in function App() in App.js with  everything inside GoogleLogin but still I got the same problem.
